# What exactly happens with fork()?

Tags: c++, process, fork

```
int main(){

    char ch;

    fork();

    cin >> c;
}
```

After calling fork() I should have 2 exact processes running the same code. Why after running this simple example, I am either asked to enter a character only once, either twice? Shouldn't  the system expect 2 inputs every single time I run this program?

```
>./a.out 
a
>./a.out
a
b
>
```

Comment: This is not C code, you're using a C++ operator, and those of us who don't speak C++ therefore cannot help you.

Comment: There is a good chance that the second process gets `\n` character that you enter right after `a`. Try changing the type of `ch` to `std::string`, and see what happens.

Comment: I just did, it acts the same way.

Comment: The other process may run as a seperate "job" since it's not just a thread but a full-blown process. See [here](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html). So try to suspend the active job (Ctrl+Z) and then list the jobs with `jobs -l` and try to bring the other job into the foreground `fg 2` (instead of `2` use the job_id of the other job).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two processes reading from the terminal at the same time.  It is anybody's guess which process gets the input.

- If the parent process gets the input first, it exits and returns control to the shell.  (Note that this actually causes a repeat of the same situation, with shell and the child process fighting for input.)
- If the child process gets the input first, it exits but control does not return to the shell untill the parent process exits.

You should not expect consistent behavior if you have two processes reading from the same terminal.

Comment: Note that in the first case, the second process will get a line of input sooner or later.  After the shell prompt, perhaps; in which case, it will seem to steal a line from the shell.

Comment: @James I doubt it: the parent process will close, and so will the child even if it hasn't received the input it was going to ask for.

Comment: @Cookie503 The parent process can't close an open fd in the child.  The question is where this fd points.  If it points to a physical terminal (an actual device), the device remains open.  If it points to a logical terminal (a window, a remote login, etc.), the logical device remains open, but where it points to or how it reacts to future IO could change, if e.g. the session group changed.

Comment: @JamesKanze +1 But does this still happen if the parent process closes before the child can even reach that part where it asks for input?

Comment: @Cookie503: "This actually causes a repeat of the same situation, with the shell and the child process fighting for input."

Comment: @Cookie503 Yes.  As soon as you fork, you have two "copies" of the open fd.  Closing one closes just that one, not both.

Answer (score 2):

When fork() is called, the operating system typically copies the entire memory space of the executing program (sort of). Both programs then run. The only differences is that in the "new" process, fork() returns 0, and in the "old" process it returns the process ID of the new process.

The reason that you're only asked for one input is that one of the programs is running in the background. The command-line shell only does I/O for one process at a time.

Answer (score 1):

fork() creates a child process.

But which process (among the parent and the newly born child) gets the CPU slice is undetermined. When both the processes are blocked for keyboard input, either the child or the parent can get the input. 
If the parent gets the token, it reads the input into its variable defined in its address space and exits. And the child never gets a chance to read from the input. And this orphaned child process will then be adopted by the 'root' process (pid=1). See `ps` output.

And in the other case, where the child gets the token and reads the data and exits, the parent is still alive and hence blocks for input again.

Comment: Even if the parent exits, the child should still be part of the same terminal group, shouldn't it?  (I'm not sure.  It's been a while since I worked at this level.)  In which case, it will get a line sooner or later---it's no longer competing with the parent, who has exited, but with the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Include a wait() after fork() and try.